# What can be said about $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$? Are these numbers rational or irrational?

Tags: exponential-function, pi, rationality-testing

"homework"

> What can be said about $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$? Are these numbers rational or irrational?

I know that both $\pi$ and $e$ are  irrational. What can be said about $\pi+e$, and $\pi e$?

Comment: This question is hardly homework...

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 13):

It is not currently known whether or not $\pi+e$ is rational. It is also not known whether or not $\pi e$ is rational. However, we can say that $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ cannot **both be rational**.

For suppose to the contrary that they are both rational. Then $(\pi+e)^2-4\pi e$ is rational. But this is $(\pi-e)^2$, so $\pi-e$ is algebraic. But then adding and subtracting $\pi+e$, we find that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraic. But in fact both are transcendental.

The same proof shows that $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ cannot be both algebraic.

**Remark:** The natural conjecture is that both $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ are transcendental. After all, "most" real numbers are. However, settling the question of transcendentality, or even irrationality, of either would represent a major mathematical achievement.